# The cotangent bundle on the flag variety

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

This has been asked previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1164660/identifying-the-cotangent-bundle-of-the-flag-variety), though the only similarity between that question and mine is their question 1 (all put below). Moreover, the top answer of that post deals with $\mathfrak{g}$ from a geometric perspective - I am interested in the other way. I also have several other questions not addressed in that post.

To begin with, Lemma 1.4.9 of Chriss and Ginzburg's "Complex Geometry and Representation Theory", re-worded to emphasise what I care about:

> There is a natural vector bundle isomorphism $T^*(G/P) \cong G \times_P \mathfrak{p}^\perp$.

**Question 1:** I am not sure how to even explicitly describe the cotangent bundle $T^*(G/P)$. Here, $P$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$. Obviously in the text, $T_e(G/P) = \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$, and similarly for $T_e^*(G/P) = \mathfrak{p}^\perp$. But is this equality the definition, or does it come as a result of the definition? And if the latter, what *is* the definition of the cotangent bundle here?

This result and the following Proposition 1.4.11 are used in the proof of Lemma 3.2.2.

> There is a natural vector bundle isomorphism $\widetilde{\mathcal{N}} \cong T^*\mathcal{B}$.

**Question 2:** I am also not sure how to explicitly describe the cotangent bundle $T^*\mathcal{B}$. Here $\mathcal{B}$ is the flag variety, i.e. the set of all Borel subalgebras $ \mathfrak{b} \subset \mathfrak{g}$.

The proof of this lemma then proceeds by using the previous result to show that $T^*\mathcal{B} = G \times_\mathcal{B} \mathfrak{b}^\perp$. I understand that there is a bijection $G/B \cong \mathcal{B}$, though admit I am not familiar with this, only that we map $g \mapsto g \cdot \mathfrak{b} \cdot g^{-1}$. Clarification here would be appreciated, though is secondary to my other questions.

Finally, in Proposition 4.1.2:

> There is a natural vector bundle isomorphism $T^* \mathcal{F} \cong M$, where $M = \{(x,F) \in \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{F} : xF_i \subset F_{i-1} \forall i\}$.

**Question 3:** The proof with $\mathcal{F}$ the flag variety is supposedly analogous to the proof of the previous result, however I don't see what the analogue of $G \times_\mathcal{B} \mathfrak{b}^\perp$ is. The text mention that the set of partial flags $\mathcal{F}$ has a smooth compact manifold structure, but I am not familiar enough with the geometry perspective - what is this structure, and how do we get the Lie (sub)algebra structure from that?

Comment: Q1 : The equality is $T^*_e(G/P) = (\mathfrak g/ \mathfrak p)^*$. But the latter is isomorphic to $\mathfrak p^{\perp}$ (just linear algebra). The definition of the cotangent bundle is the usual one in differential geometry (or algebraic geometry). Was it your question ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet The definition of the cotangent bundle I am used to working with is the dual of the tangent bundle, where the tangent bundle is $TG \cong G \times T_eG$. But that doesn't seem to answer why $T_e(G/P) = \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$, so I am unsure if this second equality is the definition they are working with, or if it somehow follows from the definition I've given above.

Comment: The tangent bundle of $TG$ is not defined as $G \times T_eG$. The isomorphism you wrote follows from the fact that left/right translation gives a trivialisation of the tangent bundle. It's a general fact that for a closed subgroup $H \subset G$ the tangent space of $G/H$ at $eH$ is $\mathfrak g/ \mathfrak h$.

Comment: @Nicolas Do you have an elementary reference for the last fact?

Comment: According to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220601/tangent-space-of-quotient-algebraic-group, the statement is Theorem 25.4.11 in the Book by Tauvel and Yu, Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups. Edit : before reading, maybe you should try to write down a proof for $G = \mathrm{SL}_n(\Bbb C)$. Also if you have several questions, it might be better to ask several questions on the website.

Comment: Got it. I asked these questions in the same post because I believe they are all very related to each other in terms of defining what exactly the cotangent bundle on $\mathcal{B}$ is - is this not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1** : The definition of the tangent/cotangent bundle is the usual definition used in differential geometry, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle) for example. However, if $G$ is a Lie group it is possible to show that there is an isomorphism of vector bundle $TG \cong G \times \mathfrak g$. This isomorphism uses the group structure, it is not true in general that $TM \cong M \times \Bbb R^m$ (where $m = \dim M$), for example $M=S^2 = \Bbb P^1$. 
The other part of question $1$ was answered in comments.

**Question 2** : Describing explicitly $T^* \mathcal B$ is precisely what is done in Chriss-Ginzburg, where they give several different descriptions. 
$\mathcal B$ is defined as the set of Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$, and it is a classical result recalled in Chriss-Ginzburg that all Borel subalgebras are conjugated. Hence $G$ acts transitively by conjugaison action on $\mathcal B$. Moreover, if we fix a special Borel $B$, then $B = \mathrm{Stab}_G(\mathfrak b)$ (since Borel are self-normalizing) which implies $\mathcal B \cong G/B$.

**Question 3** : One has $\mathcal F \cong \mathcal B$ because for example they both correspond to $G/B$, and this gives the structure of a smooth compact manifold. Alternatively, you can embedd $\mathcal F$ in a product of grassmannians.
Proposition 4.1.2 is an alternative description of $T^*(\mathcal B)$, so you should try to see it as a different description of the same object, rather as a similar description. For example it is not obvious at all that $M$ has the structure of smooth variety, let alone a vector bundle over $\mathcal B$ !

Comment: On Q2: Chriss-Ginzburg give the isomorphism of $T^* \mathcal{B} \cong \widetilde{\mathcal{N}}$, but what I am looking for is the definition of $T^∗ \mathcal{B}$. On Q3: Why does $\mathcal{F}$ correspond to $G/B$ in this situation? The alternative description as an embedding in a product of Grassmannians is also mentioned but not clear to me.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : $\mathcal B$ is a manifold, and $T^* \mathcal B$ is the usual cotangent bundle of a manifold. Q3 : How do you define $\mathcal F$ ? If it's the space of flag, $\mathcal F$ is actually $\mathrm{SL}_n/B$. It's because $\mathrm{SL}_n$ acts transitively on $\mathcal F$, and the stabiliser of $\{ \langle e_1 \rangle \subset  \langle e_1,e_2 \rangle \subset \dots \subset \mathbb C^n \}$ is exactly given by $B$.

Comment: I think I have understood my issue for Q2 - a reference for the manifold structure on $\mathcal{B}$ would be enough to answer this. Similarly for Q3, why $\mathcal{F}$ is a manifold. I have found [these lecture notes](http://uregina.ca/~mareal/flag-coh.pdf), which do not entirely explain the situation to me, and further instead say that $\mathcal{F} = \text{GL}_n/B$.

Comment: Look at theorem 21.10 in "Introduction to smooth manifolds" by John Lee. Also, $SL_n/B$ and $GL_n/B$ are the same, notice that $B$ is different in both case.

Comment: Please see [this new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504997/fiber-product-g-times-b-mathfrakn-as-a-vector-bundle-over-the-flag-variety) I posted - I think that may better clarify this answer for me.

Comment: I'll mark this question as solved, but I would have also liked to see how the quotient manifold structure on $\mathcal{B}$ or $\mathcal{F}$ would translate in defining the tangent bundles, since the definition of tangent bundles using derivations/tangent curves is not clear to me. But I think that is a different question to originally stated, and can be found elsewhere.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : In my opinion, the description as $G \times^B \mathfrak n$ or as $\widetilde{\mathcal N}$ are much better. Beside, this is more or less a general fact that $T(G/H) = G \times^H \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{h}$. You will see in the book that you will never use a parametrised curve or anything like this, so a description with tangent curves is not so useful.

Comment: I don't believe $\mathcal{F} \cong \mathcal{B}$, since the latter is Borel subalgebras whereas we should really be looking parabolic subalgebras...

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : partial flag correspond to $G/P$. Also a Borel subalgebra is a special case of a parabolic subalgebra.

Comment: Yes, so it's not true in general that $F \cong B$, rather $F \cong P$ where $P$ is the set of conjugacy classes of parabolic subgroups, is this not true?

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : it is true if you consider the set of complete flag $\mathcal F$ which is canonically isomorphic to $\mathcal B$. If you take some partial flag variety $\mathcal F'$, there will be a parabolic $P$ so that $\mathcal F' \cong G/P$.

Comment: In the case of Ch 4, we take $\mathcal{F}$ the space of partial flags. For each connected component $\mathcal{F}_d$ (i.e. each partial flag variety?), there is a parabolic $P$ so that $\mathcal{F}_d \cong G/P$. Then the entire space $\mathcal{F}$ should be equivalent to $\mathcal{P}$, the latter being the set of conjugacy classes of all parabolics. Is this not correct?

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : In this case $\mathcal F = \sqcup_{P} G/P$, where $P$ run through all parabolic subgroup.