# Fiber product $G \times_B \mathfrak{n}$ as a vector bundle over the flag variety

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-bundles

This is from the discussion of Section 3.2 of Chriss and Ginzburg's "Rep Theory and Complex Geometry" text.

Fix $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_n(V)$ (with $V = \mathbb{C}^n)$, and let $\mathcal{N}$ denote the set of nilpotent elements of $\mathfrak{g}$. Additionally, let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the set of Borel subalgebras $\mathfrak{b} \subset \mathfrak{g}$, and define $\mathcal{N}' := \{(x,\mathfrak{b}) \in \mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{B} : x \in \mathcal{b}\}$. I understand why it is a vector bundle over $\mathcal{B}$.

In this specific case, we have a fixed Borel subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ (and its corresponding Borel subgroup $B$), with weight space decomposition $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$. By Engel's theorem, for nilpotent element $x \in \mathcal{N}$, there exists a basis for $V$ such that the matrix representation of $x$ lies in $\mathfrak{n}$.

The text then claims that this gives an isomorphism of vector bundles $\mathcal{N}' \cong G \times_B \mathfrak{n}$, but I do not see why. More specifically, I am not entirely sure what the maps $G \to B$ and $\mathfrak{n} \to B$ should be in the fiber product, which may be part of the reason I do not get this claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a fiber product. It's why I think a better notation is $G \times^B \mathfrak n$. Also be careful with the notations : usually $B$ is a fixed Borel (in $G/B$ for example) and sometimes it may vary. So here we fix a Borel subgroup $B$.

Anyway, the construction is as follows : if $H \subset G$ is a closed subgroup and $E$ is a $H$-module, we can construct a vector bundle over $G/H$ given by $G \times^H E := (G \times E)/H$. Here $H$ acts by $h \cdot (g,e) = (gh, \rho(h^{-1})e)$. The construction is detailed [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/notes13.pdf).

You can look at the map $\beta : G \times^B \mathfrak n \to \mathcal N'$, sending $(gB,x) \mapsto (Ad_g(x),gB)$, where $Ad_g(x)$ is the adjoint action, i.e $gxg^{-1}$ for matrix groups.

Now the claim follows if we can show that the map $G \times^B \mathfrak n \to \mathcal N'$ is an isomorphism (because we saw that $G \times^B \mathfrak n$ is a naturally a vector bundle over $\mathcal B$.) I think it is proved in Chriss-Ginzburg, but let us give the proof.

The maps is clearly surjective, since for any $x \in \mathfrak b'$ nilpotent, we have $\beta(g,Ad_g^{-1}(x)) = (x, \mathfrak b')$, where $gB \in \mathcal B$ correspond to $\mathfrak b'$.

Suppose $\beta(g,x) = \beta(g', x')$. Then, $gB = g'B$, so there is $b \in B$, such that $g = g'b$. From this and the equality $Ad_g(x) = Ad_{g'}(x')$ it is easy to conclude that $(g,x) = (g',x')$ in $G \times^B \mathfrak n$.

EDIT : In fact, the map $\beta$ was already constructed before in Corollary 3.1.33, to show the isomorphism $G \times^B \mathfrak b \cong \widetilde{\mathfrak g}$. Hence, to show that $G \times^B \mathfrak n \to \mathcal N'$, you just need to show surjectivity, which follows from the fact that all Borel are conjugated.

Comment: 1: It is not clear to me how $\mathfrak{n}$ is a $B$-module, what representation is it?
2: I believe that $G \times^B \mathfrak{n} \cong \mathcal{N}$ since their fibers over each point is $\mathfrak{n}$ - surely the map defined is overkill here?
3: In the proof of injectivity, I disagree that $gB = g'B$ implies existence of $b \in B$ so that $bgb^{-1} = g'$.

Comment: Additionally - I would like to understand how Chriss-Ginzburg conclude the same vector bundle isomorphism only with the justification in my OP, that "any nilpotent element of $\mathfrak{g}$ is $G$-conjugate into $\mathfrak{n}..."

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : 1 Use the adjoint action. 2 The fiber of $\mathcal N'$ over $\mathcal B$ is NOT $\mathfrak n$ in general, but $\mathfrak n' := [\mathfrak b', \mathfrak b']$. You need the map. With such a argument, you could deduce that any vector bundle is trivial. 3 Yes I meant $b \in B$ so that $g = g'b$, I edited that.
"Additionally ..." : what you really need I think is that any Borel is conjugated, from which you can easily deduce that any nilpotent is conjugated to $\mathfrak n$ (because any nilpotent is contained in at least a Borel subalgebra).

Comment: And yes, as in the OP, I understand all Borel subalgebras are conjugate, hence any nilpotent is conjugate into $\mathfrak{n}$. What I do not understand is how this leads to the vector bundle isomorphism, as Chriss-Ginzburg conclude. They do not use the map defined in your answer - if you could clarify your answer with this alternate approach, I would consider it answered - thanks!

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : 1) Really, they should have say "since all Borel are conjugated, for each nilpotent in $\mathfrak b'$ there is $x \in \mathfrak n$ such that ...". 2) They do use the map, which in fact was introduced earlier in corollary 3.1.33. This is mostly why they don't give detail about the isomorphism $G \times^B \mathfrak n \cong \mathcal N'$. I edited the answer to incorporate this.

Comment: Apologies for taking up so much of your time. But what I do not understand is that $G \times^B \mathfrak{n}$ is a bundle which has fibre $\mathfrak{n}$ over each $\mathfrak{b} \in \mathcal{B}$. By the discussion in the text, $\mathcal{N}'$ is also a bundler which has fibre $\mathfrak{n}$ over each point, this $\mathfrak{n}$ fixed. What am I missing here in the isomorphism that requires more to say?

Comment: Unless they mean to say $\mathfrak{n}$ is the fibre over each $\mathfrak{b}$ - actually that makes more sense. I believe this answers my question.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : a vector bundle is not determined uniquely by its fibers. Again, else all vector bundles will be isomorphic. What you really need is a map like $\beta$ that globally glue them together.

Comment: I was of the understanding that two bundles with isomorphic fibres are themselves isomorphic, but this is clearly not the case. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nhmwhhxx : but the fiber of a vector bundle has a priori no other structure than a vector space, so this is why I was saying that it would imply that all vector bundles are isomorphic. I would suggest to read a bit more about homogeneous spaces, Lie groups and vector bundles (for example vector bundles on $\Bbb P^1$). This book assume a strong understanding of these, and is often skipping details as you probably already noticed. (On the other hand, I think that's a wonderful book !!)